# SD Card pins dimensions

Tags: datasheet, sd, dimensions

I am trying to create an SD card from a PCB. My problem is that I cannot find the SD card specification that would give the:

1. Dimensions of each Pin
2. Placement of each Pin

All specifications I could find dont consist of those informations:

[image: image description here]

Does anyone know where I could find this data? I would appreciate all help.

Comment: http://www.convict.lu/pdf/ProdManualSDCardv1.9.pdf : page 22/113. You can also look at mechanical plans of SD connectors. (And the bad news : You may need a licence from the SD cartel if you want to make a commercial product such as an SD card emulator... Alternatively, there is the JEDEC MMC standard which may suit your needs)

Comment: @TEMLIB Good answer, now if you would only have written it in the right place it could have been voted on, improved by edits, and accepted as an answer - like Stack Exchange is supposed to work.

Comment: @pipe. Great. I'm a rebel ;-), let's break Stack Exchange! And, above that, I'm lazy, and making a proper answer would have meant copying, cropping the picture, or even recreate a neat mechanical plan. (I have made a nice SVG SD card image for my website, if you are in the mood, you can copy it, add measures, post the "definitive" answer and get all the fame and glory! I will upvote, promised)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you are looking for is given in the SD card physical layer specifications, published by the SD association. The SD association only makes the simplified specifications available from their website (see https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/). Unfortunately, the simplified physical specifications don't give the details of the contact locations: they only give the overall physical dimensions of the SD card.

And, to quote their website:

> Simplified versions of selected SD memory card specifications are available for download by developers. To get access to the full specifications, **simply** [sic] join the SD Association.

Of course, joining will cost you the ridiculously low amount of 2,500$ (annual fees).

Fortunately, internet is a great place (for illegal things) and you can easily find older versions of the specs anyway. I'm shamelessly giving a random link because I find it unacceptable that you should pay for that (and giving a link isn't forbidden by law, only the owner of the linked website is doing something prohibited here):

https://www.elabpeers.com/productattachments/index/download?id=28

You can find what you need at page 107.

Alternatively (if the link above goes dead due to a cease and desist letter), you could find the information in some detailed datasheets from various SD card vendors, for example at the link given by @TEMLIB (in the comment above):

http://www.convict.lu/pdf/ProdManualSDCardv1.9.pdf